# Javascript scope issue, ajax

Tags: ajax, scope, this

I want to submit a form using ajax, then add a "disabled" class if the ajax request succeeds.

```
$("body").on("click", ".my_form", function(e){
    submit_form(e, $(this));    
});

function submit_form(e, _this){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/controller/common/form_processing.php", 
        data: "my form data goes here",
        dataType: "json", 
        success:function (data, _this) {
            _this.parents(".my_form").addClass("disabled");
       });
});
```

In it's current form, the "disabled" class is *not* being added. However, if I move the line: `_this.parents(".thumbsup").addClass("disabled");` outside of the ajax brackets, it does work. (but obviously in this case, "disabled" will be added regardless of whether the ajax call succeeds or fails. Can somebody explain how to get this working properly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `_this` parameter from your success callback, you are redefining `_this` over the original one which is the jQuery object passed to `submit_form`

```
success:function (data) {
    _this.parents(".my_form").addClass("disabled");
});
```